# How can I get all the tr elements of a table and filter them using jquery?

Tags: jquery, arrays, filter, rows

I'm trying to grab all table rows in a table then filter them out by if they have a class on them titled "hideGroup." This is my code so far but it just keeps outputting numbers. What would be the proper way to grab all the table rows in a table and then check to see if they have a group called "hideGroup?"

```
 var newRows = $("#search-results-table").find("tr");

        var filteredRows = newRows.filter(function(n) {
            if (n.className != "hideGroup")
                return n;
        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is not that clear.

Use `:not()` if you like to select all rows that **do not** have the class

```
$('#search-results-table tr:not(.hideGroup)')
```

If you like to only filter the ones with that class use:

```
$('#search-results-table tr.hideGroup');
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('#search-results-table tr.hideGroup')` would return the full set.

### Edit:

If it's true that you want rows **without** the class `hideGroup`, despite explicitly saying `check to see if they have a group called "hideGroup?"`, here's the selector to do that:

`$('#search-results-table tr').not('.hideGroup')`

Comment: he wants tr's that DONT have the class hideGroup

Comment: sorry - his question is slightly confused, after reading it again I'm not sure exactly what he wants

Comment: @dormisher True, his question is confused, but I think you're right.  The code he gave seemed to **exclude** the `tr`s with that class, so I think you were on the right path.  Poor wording of the question, no doubt.

Answer (score 1):

To return a collection all of the table rows with "hideGroup" class use:

```
$('#search-results-table tr.hideGroup')
```

to filter the classes that do **not** have the "hideGroup" class use:

```
$('#search-results-table tr:not(.hideGroup)')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#search-results-table tr:not(.hideGroup)')
```

That will return all table rows that do not have the hideGroup class

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's returning numbers is because `n` is an index (number), not an element. so `n.className` will always be `undefined` which will make your logic inside that function always return `n`.

What you want to use is either select the results by using

```
$('#search-results-table tr.hideGroup')
```

or

```
$('#search-results-table tr:not(.hideGroup)')
```

Answer (score 0):

When using a function with `jQuery.filter()`,  the first parameter is the index, not the element. You can fix this by using `this` instead:

```
var newRows = $("#search-results-table").find("tr");

var filteredRows = newRows.filter(function(n) {
  return !$(this).hasClass('hideGroup');
});
```

However, take a look at some of the other answers. They provide a much shorter solution.